# MediaWiki sitemap generator

Tags: sitemap, mediawiki

I'm using mediawiki for my site. I'm trying several ways to generate sitemap but it doesn't work. Anyone knows how to generate sitemap for MediaWiki and alert to Google automatically?

Answer (score 4):

> Note: Since MediaWiki 1.6, the MediaWiki core has a Google site map
>   generator... It is a
>   command-line utility, and it is located at
>   maintenance/generateSitemap.php in your MediaWiki directory. The
>   command line is "php generateSitemap.php sitename" and is run from the
>   maintenance directory at the server's command line interface. See
>   [Manual:generateSitemap.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aGenerateSitemap.php) for more information.

From http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ManualSitemap.

Comment: Do you know how to use     Manual:generateSitemap.php? I want to use native sitemap generator of MediaWiki.

Comment: Have you read what's on this page? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aGenerateSitemap.php

Comment: Of course, I did read. But the maintenance scripts must be run from the command line but I'm using a shared host.

Comment: So your next question is "how do I run something from the command line when I'm using a shared host?". If you don't ask it then I will.

Comment: I just did: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/how-do-i-run-something-from-the-command-line-on-shared-hosting

Comment: There's no way simpler? I used Wordpress and has a plugin named Sitemap Generator very simple to use. Why so MediaWiki was very complicated?

Comment: @trancuong: If your webhost really doesn't give you access to a shell or to cron jobs, you could try installing the [Maintenance Shell extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MaintenanceShell) which lets you run MediaWiki maintenance scripts from a special page on your wiki.