# How do I run something from the command line on shared hosting?

Tags: shared-hosting, cron

I have shared hosting and they haven't given me command line (or ssh or shell) access. Is there a way that I can run something from the command line?

Comment: A lot of shared hosting providers include shell access. I would switch to one if possible. SSH is such a basic tool, it's going to better for you in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shared hosting may give you access to cron jobs. (On cPanel hosting this may be under Advanced Tools.) Cron is a Unix command which runs a task at a specified time. You can create a cron job to run the task you want, if your shared hosting lets you.

cPanel gives this warning though:

> You need to have knowledge of *nix commands before you can use cron
>   jobs effectively. Check your script with your hosting administrator
>   before adding a cron job.

Comment: cPanel is not a console.

Answer (score 3):

cron is your best bet if you want to run something periodically.

If you just want to run a few shell commands (and depending on the security restrictions of your host) have a look at php's [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) and [shell_exec function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

I have had success with phpshell and phpsh projects too.